# Error while assigning admin role to SCIM provisioned AAD groups in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

We use Azure databricks and managing via terraform. We have configured SCIM connector provisioner(AAD Enterprise app) to sync users and groups from AAD to Databricks. This works good. I can able to assign job or cluster permissions to these SCIM synced groups but when I try to assign admin role(entire workspace admin) to SCIM synced group the terraform error shows "API is not available for this worspace". Sorry, I don't what it means, Is it related to terraform provider or Am I putting something wrong? Please suggest me what should I use or correct. Please find below code 'principal_id' argument accepts user id or group id or service principal id as per terraform documentation here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/permission_assignment#principal_id

Provider configuration:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.4"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.8.0"
    }
      databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = ">= 1.6.3"
    }
  }
}


provider "databricks" { #Assign databricks workspace id to provider
  azure_workspace_resource_id = 
     data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.adb_ws.id
}
```

Resource Block:

```
resource "databricks_permission_assignment" "assign_scim_admingroup" {
  principal_id = data.databricks_group.dbricks_admin_group.id
  permissions  = ["ADMIN"]
}
```

Error in terraform:

```
│ Error: cannot create permission assignment: Permission assignment APIs are not available for this workspace.
│ 
│   with databricks_permission_assignment.assign_scim_admingroup,
│   on Dbricks-permission.tf line 104, in resource "databricks_permission_assignment" "assign_scim_admingroup":
│   43: resource "databricks_permission_assignment" "assign_scim_admingroup" {
```

My expectation is Databricks group synced with AAD via SCIM connecter provisioner groups should be assigned as "ADMIN" role using terraform.

Comment: Do you have unit catalog metastore attached to this workspace?

Comment: also, please post the provider configuration

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for looking for me. We just use hive metastore and this also by default (we haven't configured anything) and we're not using unity catalog. I've added provider code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for us was that we were creating the metastore and the user permission assignments in the same Terraform apply. It turns out that the metastore needs about 10 minutes of buffer time, so if you run the same Terraform apply after 10 minutes it should work. Hope this helps

Comment: Same here. Did you find any workaround to have a succesfull run in one run?

Comment: @FredericDS nah

Comment: I've added a timeout in Terraform. Not ideal bit it works

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

**Code:**

```
resource "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "kavyaMyGroup"
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  security_enabled = true

  members = [
    azuread_user.example.object_id,
    # more users 
   ]
}
resource "databricks_user" "me" {
 // user_name    = "testuser@databricks.com"
 user_name = azuread_user.example.user_principal_name
  display_name = "Test User"
}




resource "databricks_group" "this" {
//  display_name               = "vsakaSomeGroup"
display_name = azuread_group.example.display_name
  allow_cluster_create       = true
  allow_instance_pool_create = true
  workspace_access      = true
  databricks_sql_access = true
}

resource "databricks_group_member" "vip_member" {
  group_id = databricks_group.this.id
  member_id = databricks_user.me.id
}
```

**I received the same error:**

```
│ Error: cannot create permission assignment: Permission assignment APIs are not available for this workspace.
│
│   with databricks_permission_assignment.assign_scim_admingroup,
│   on main.tf line 145, in resource "databricks_permission_assignment" "assign_scim_admingroup":
```

[image]

**Please note :**

> The admins group is a reserved group in Azure Databricks and cannot be
> removed. Note that Workspace-local groups cannot be [granted
> access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/automate?source=recommendations#configure-access-grants-for-a-view) to data in a Unity Catalog metastore or assigned to other
> workspaces .

> To add groups to a workspace using the account console,
> `the workspace must be enabled for identity federation`. **`Only account-level groups are assignable.`**

[Manage groups - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/groups)

- If I checked my environment, the group created is local and not
  account level , so I did not have permissions to assign admin role to
  it.

[image]

The account admins can assign them using ,the principal ID which can be retrieved using the SCIM API.

```
resource "databricks_permission_assignment" "assign_scim_admingroup" {
 /principal_id = databricks_group.this.id
  permissions  = ["ADMIN"]
}
```

Make sure to ***`enable identity federation`*** , to assign group roles  and have **premium plan** in order to manage the assignment of users to workspaces

[image]

You can also check Automate SCIM provisioning using Microsoft Graph from

**Reference:** [Configure SCIM provisioning using Microsoft Azure Active Directory - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/scim/aad)

Comment: Hi Kavya, Thanks for your answer. I have tried above directly add user to databricks from AD provider but this will be static e.g. whenever we need to remove user, we need to run the code. So, SCIM option came up. Now, we granted 'admin' access to single databricks user imported from AD SCIM connection. Kind of similar to your proposal though. Need to check on other efficient  way. Thanks